# MySQL query: Slow response when joining table using ifnull

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, `products`, `variants`, and `data`.

Each product has it's own `productcode`. Products can have any number of variants including none. Variants have their own code `variantcode`. Products have a `productid` column, and each variant has a related `productid` column.

I want a list of all the codes, but I only care about the `productcode` if a product has no variants. Otherwise I want the `variantcode`. I wrote this query to get this list:

```
SELECT IFNULL(variants.variantcode, products.productcode) AS code 
FROM products 
LEFT OUTER JOIN variants ON (products.productid = variants.productid) 
ORDER BY code
```

This query works as I expected.

The `data` table contains extra data for each code. I want to join this data onto this list. I tried this query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(variants.variantcode, products.productcode) AS code 
FROM products 
LEFT OUTER JOIN variants ON (products.productid = variants.productid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN data ON (data.partno = code) 
ORDER BY code
```

But I get an error "Unknown column 'code' in 'on clause'". I assumed this had something to do with `code` being a generated value, so I then tried this query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(variants.variantcode, products.productcode) AS code 
FROM products 
LEFT OUTER JOIN variants ON (products.productid = variants.productid) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN data ON (data.partno = IFNULL(variants.variantcode, products.productcode)) 
ORDER BY code
```

This query worked, but took a long time (~20 seconds vs <1 second for the first query). Is the IFNULL in the ON clause the problem? How can I speed it up?

Comment: You need to use a derived query for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 select product_variants.code from

 (SELECT IFNULL(variants.variantcode, products.productcode) AS code 
 FROM products 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN variants ON (products.productid = variants.productid) 
 ORDER BY code) 

 as product_variants

 LEFT OUTER JOIN data ON (data.partno = product_variants.code)
```

Comment: That did the trick! After posting this I looked into derived queries as recommended by @njk, and wrote a query like this: 

`SELECT product_variants.code FROM

 (SELECT IFNULL(variants.variantcode, products.productcode) AS code 
 FROM products 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN variants ON (products.productid = variants.productid)) 
 
AS product_variants
LEFT OUTER JOIN data ON (data.partno = product_variants.code) 
ORDER BY product_variants.code`
 
 Which worked, but still took 20 seconds. Why does moving the ORDER BY speed it up?

Comment: You can check how the execution plan is affected by adding the `EXPLAIN` keyword in front of the query like `EXPLAIN select product_variants.code...` It'll show if indexes were used and the estimated number of rows returned.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Adrian. I spent a little time looking at the EXPLAIN, and it wasn't using any index on `data`. I tried modifying the indexes, but none were being used. Turns out the `partno` field using a different collation than `productcode` and `variantcode`. This was due to a mistake on my part when I made the table. I changed the collation to match, and now my queries are running fast.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to join to your `data` table twice, something like this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(variants.variantcode, products.productcode) AS code
     , IFNULL(D1.something, D2.something) AS something 
FROM products 
LEFT OUTER JOIN variants
ON (products.productid = variants.productid) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN data as D1
ON (D1.partno = variants.variantcode) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN data as D2
ON (D2.partno = products.productcode) 
ORDER BY code
```

Comment: That seems like it would work, but wouldn't that require an IFNULL for every column in `data`?

Comment: Yes it would; it wasn't clear from your question that you needed all columns in `data`.  Using a derived table as above is likely best; I was just showing a different way.

Comment: Ahh ok. I had an idea in my head similar to this, so it was nice to see it written out. Thanks!